# Comparing 2D string array with itself

Tags: java, arrays, intersection

For my assignment I am required to find the intersection of arrays and print out the Jaccard index, which is the magnitude of the intersection divided by the magnitude of the union of the two arrays. I need to figure out a way to compare the arrays with themselves, given that each array is part of the same 2-D array, and each element of each array is a string with 2 characters.

For my base input, the example i am using while i create it, the 2-D array contains 3 arrays which are compared with each other, and themselves. The print out is in the form of a 3x3 square, where (1,1),(2,2), and (3,3) are all going to be 1, because it would be comparing an array to itself. Likewise, (1,2) and (2,1) are the same, and (2,3) and (3,2) are the same.

I know the comparing will probably need to be done with a nested loop, because of the 2-D iterations.

Comment: Write a function to compare two arrays, then call it from a loop like `for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) result[i][j] = compare(arr[i], arr[j]);`

Comment: Have you a question?

Comment: The question was, how to compare it. I know how to do loops. How am I supposed to actually compare it though?

Comment: Compare what, exactly? Why would you be comparing an array with itself, since it'll always be identical?

Comment: In that case, it would be returning 1. In the case of comparing an array with one of the other arrays in the 2-D string array, it would not be 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your question, but arrays of the same type shouldn't be difficult to compare.

The Jaccard index is the size of the intersection of sets A and B, divided by the size of the union of sets A and B. The way I see it you should have four functions, plus a main function:

#### jaccardIndex(array1, array2)

```
// Get the size of union(array1, array2)
// Get the size of intersect(array1, array2)
// return intersectSize / unionSize (as long as unionSize != 0)
```

#### union(array1, array2)

```
// Create new array to return
// Iterate through array1
// Any element in array1 that isn't in array2 (!isElementOf), add it to the new array
// return the new array
```

#### intersect(array1, array2)

```
// Create new array to return
// Iterate through array1
// Any element that is in array1 that is also in array2(isElementOf), add it to the new array
// return the new array
```

#### isElementOf(value, array)

```
// Iterate through array
// If a given element equals the value, return true
```

#### main(args[])

```
// Initialize your arrays here,
// Utilize jaccardIndex
```